# Component design hierearchy in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have recently started learning React. I want to create two components - **Input** and **Display**. Input has a textfield and a button. When I type something and submit the button, the value of the textfield should be passed as a prop to Display and the Display should output the value.

How to approach the design? What is the component hierarchy?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question in isolation. If `<Input>` *includes* `<Display>`, e.g., it's sending the value directly, that answers your hierarchy question. If they're intended to be used separately, then there *is* no hierarchy, they're just separate components that don't know anything about each other, and the job of marshalling the data to send to `<Display>` falls under the purview of whichever component renders them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ['lift up'](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) the value from the text input to the display prop via it's shared ancestor component.

Here is an example of 'lifting up' state with `useState` in the functional style:

```js
const Input = ({ setValue }) => {
  return <input onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)} />
}

const Display = ({ value }) => {
  return <div>{value}</div>
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')
  
  return <div>
    <Input setValue={setValue} />
    <Display value={value} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you provide what you have at the moment, then it'll be easier to answer; otherwise I'll just be writing the whole code instead of letting you learn.

One way is to implement a callback function that sets the state in Display with text field's value when Input button is clicked. Display should be the one passing this function as a prop to Input. Input calls this function when button is clicked with the text field's value.

Then whatever is rending Display's state will output the value appropriately.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I was not sure about it. Let me give it a try. Thanks!